# Cancelling a paid Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, isv

Our organization is planning to cancel a managed package, which we have alot of custom development around, i.e. triggers on the managed objects and Visualforce pages that reference the managed fields.

When cancelling a subscription for a managed package, does the seller have the ability to uninstall their package - if so, what happens to the components to reference the package and if not, what is the seller able to do to keep us from using an app that we are no longer paying for?

Sorry if this is too basic of a question, but all the documentation I found was about uninstalling packages that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the managed package is using the [License Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/), access to objects and fields from the managed package are blocked when the licensing is turned off there. So while it is your org meaning they (probably) can't do an uninstall, they can turn access off via the licensing mechanism so you have to face that prospect.

So you will need to negotiate with the seller to find an equitable way forward.

Comment: So how would that affect other components that reference the objects?

Comment: @brezotom Those components will fail with a runtime error if the objects are no longer licensed.